# SQL Query To Obtain Value that Occurs more than once

Tags: sql

I need to query my database to show the records inside my table where lastname occurs more than three times. Example: in my Students Table, there are 3 people with Lastname 'Smith', 4 with 'Johnson', and 1 with 'Potter'. My query should show the records of those with the lastnames Smith, and Johnson since these values occur more than or equal to 3 times.

Can anyone point me to this? I was thinking of using COUNT() but I can't seem to think how to apply it?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005+

```
;WITH T AS
(
SELECT *, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Lastname) as Cnt
FROM Students
)
SELECT * /*TODO: Add column list. Don't use "*"                   */
FROM T
WHERE Cnt >= 3
```

Comment: works also for bigquery :)

Answer (score 72):

From Oracle (but **works** in most SQL DBs):

```
SELECT LASTNAME, COUNT(*)
FROM STUDENTS
GROUP BY LASTNAME
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

P.S. it's **faster** one, because you have no Select withing Select methods here

Comment: Great answer. It was generic enough to easily convert to the simple task I had at hand.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me in a BigQuery SQL request, really fast in addition !

Comment: what if I want to return the duplicate records instead of grouping?

Answer (score 14):

For MySQL:

```
SELECT lastname AS ln 
    FROM 
    (SELECT lastname, count(*) as Counter 
     FROM `students` 
     GROUP BY `lastname`) AS tbl WHERE Counter > 2
```

Answer (score 11):

The answers mentioned here is quite elegant https://stackoverflow.com/a/6095776/1869562 but upon testing, I realize it only returns the last name.
What if you want to return the entire record itself ?
Do this
(For Mysql)

```
SELECT *
FROM `beneficiary`
WHERE `lastname`
IN (

  SELECT `lastname`
  FROM `beneficiary`
  GROUP BY `lastname`
  HAVING COUNT( `lastname` ) >1
)
```

Comment: It should also work in all DBMSs as it is ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT LASTNAME, COUNT(*)
FROM STUDENTS
GROUP BY LASTNAME
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: The OP wants "the records of those with the lastnames Smith, and Johnson" not just the last names themselves.

Comment: Where is the part which tackles OP's requirement _"values occur more than or equal to 3 times"_.

Answer (score 3):

For postgresql:

```
SELECT * AS rec 
FROM (
    SELECT lastname, COUNT(*) AS counter 
    FROM students 
    GROUP BY lastname) AS tbl 
WHERE counter > 1;
```

Comment: It should also work in all DBMSs as it is ANSI SQL.

Answer (score -1):

I think this answer can also work (it may require a little bit of modification though) :

```
SELECT * FROM Students AS S1 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT Lastname, count(*) FROM Students AS S2 GROUP BY Lastname HAVING COUNT(*) > 3 WHERE S2.Lastname = S1.Lastname)
```

Comment: Please explain why your solution works for the OP's question. Link only answers are not considered good practice. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer