# See whether an item appears more than once in a database column

Tags: sql

I want to check if a piece of data appears more than once in a particular column in my table using SQL. Here is my SQL code of what I have so far:

```
select * from AXDelNotesNoTracking where count(salesid) > 1
```

`salesid` is the column I wish to check for, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what variety of SQL? MySQL? Microsoft SQL Server? Oracle? Access? etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Query To Obtain Value that Occurs more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095567/sql-query-to-obtain-value-that-occurs-more-than-once)

Answer (score 169, accepted):

It should be:

```
SELECT SalesID, COUNT(*)
FROM AXDelNotesNoTracking
GROUP BY SalesID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Regarding your initial query:

1. You cannot do a SELECT * since this operation requires a GROUP BY
   and columns need to either be in the GROUP BY or in an aggregate
   function (i.e. COUNT, SUM, MIN, MAX, AVG, etc.)
2. As this is a GROUP BY operation, a HAVING clause will filter it
   instead of a WHERE

Edit:

And I just thought of this, if you want to see WHICH items are in there more than once (but this depends on which database you are using):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SalesID ORDER BY SalesID) AS [Num]
    FROM    AXDelNotesNoTracking
)
SELECT  *
FROM    cte
WHERE   cte.Num > 1
```

Of course, this just shows the rows that have appeared with the same SalesID but does not show the initial SalesID value that has appeared more than once. Meaning, if a SalesID shows up 3 times, this query will show instances 2 and 3 but not the first instance. Still, it might help depending on why you are looking for multiple SalesID values.

Edit2:

The following query was posted by APC below and is better than the CTE I mention above in that it shows all rows in which a SalesID has appeared more than once. I am including it here for completeness. I merely added an ORDER BY to keep the SalesID values grouped together. The ORDER BY might also help in the CTE above.

```
SELECT *
FROM AXDelNotesNoTracking
WHERE SalesID IN
    (     SELECT SalesID
          FROM AXDelNotesNoTracking
          GROUP BY SalesID
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
ORDER BY SalesID
```

Comment: This is very helpful.  I really appreciate all the varying ways of doing this and explanations.  Thanks - Leo

Comment: What about the performance issue? will SELECT SalesID, COUNT(*)
FROM AXDelNotesNoTracking
GROUP BY SalesID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 be fast?

Answer (score 17):

How about:

```
select salesid from AXDelNotesNoTracking group by salesid having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Think this is the best option, since it wont requires unecessary subquerys like in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [Solomon Rutzky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9737002/1501497), if you are looking for a piece of data that shows up in a range (i.e. more than once but less than 5x), you can use

```
having count(*) > 1 and count(*) < 5
```

And you can use whatever qualifiers you desire in there - they don't have to match, it's all just included in the 'having' statement.
https://webcheatsheet.com/sql/interactive_sql_tutorial/sql_having.php

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select salesid,count (salesid) from AXDelNotesNoTracking group by salesid having count (salesid) >1
```

Comment: -1 This is missing the HAVING clause to identify only the records that appear more than once, as the original question is requesting.

Comment: he didn't mention that he only wants to see the more than 1 records but to check them

Comment: The question states: "I want to check if a piece of data appears more than once in a particular column". Without the HAVING clause you will get back all values and if the table is large then it will be difficult to find the ones that appear more than once.