# MySQL Query To For Value that Occurs more than once for the same clientId

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL table with the below schema:

Table - `charges`

```
+=============+==============+
|  chargeName |  clientId    |
+=============+==============+
|  late fee   |    123456    |
+-------------+--------------+
|  late fee   |    123456    |
+-------------+--------------+
|   payment   |    123456    |
+-------------+--------------+
|   refund    |    782151    |
+-------------+--------------+
|  late fee   |    782151    |
+-------------+--------------+
```

I need to return instances where the `chargeName` "late fee" appears more than once for the same `clientId`.

For example, given the above, I would expect my query to return "123456" because that `clientId` has 2 "late fees" associated with it.

I tried adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6095776/1376624) from [SQL Query To Obtain Value that Occurs more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095567/sql-query-to-obtain-value-that-occurs-more-than-once)

```
SELECT clientId  
FROM 
    (SELECT chargeName, count(*) as Counter, clientId  
     FROM charges
     GROUP BY `chargeName`) 
AS tbl 
WHERE Counter > 1
AND chargeName='late fee'
limit 1000;
```

However, this query returns only one row (from my much larger dataset) and the clientId that is returned only has 1 late fee associated with it so clearly it is not working.

**How can I return instances where the `chargeName` "late fee" appears more than once for the same `clientId`.**

Comment: it's a group by `having` count>1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by GROUP BY and HAVING.

```
SELECT clientID, chargeName
FROM charges
WHERE chargeName LIKE 'late fee'
GROUP BY clientID HAVING count(clientID) > 1
```