# Display product id and total quantity for products that have been sold more than once

Tags: rdbms

> Display product id and total quantity for products that have been sold
> more than once. Consider only those sale instances when the quantity
> sold was more than 1.

DATABASE Structure given

> ```
> Salesman (Sid, Sname, Location)
> Product (Prodid, Pdesc, Price, Category, Discount)
> Sale (Saleid, Sid, Sldate, Amount)
> Saledetail (Saleid, Prodid, Quantity)
> ```

My answer

```
SELECT Prodid, MAX(SUM(Quantity)) "QTY_SOLD"
FROM Saledetail
GROUP BY Prodid HAVING Quantity>1;
```

I am not getting expected output. What's wrong in this query?

EXPECTED OUTPUT

| PRODID | QTY_SOLD |
| --- | --- |
| 102 | 11 |

Comment: What are the actual values you are getting?

Comment: Duplicate of [SQL Query To Obtain Value that Occurs more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6095567/3404097)

Comment: How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]
[mre]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Prodid,MAX(SUM(Quantity)) "QTY_SOLD" FROM Saledetail 
where Quantity>1 --** filters data itself before the aggregation
GROUP BY Prodid;  

SELECT Prodid,MAX(SUM(Quantity)) "QTY_SOLD" FROM Saledetail 
GROUP BY Prodid 
HAVING Quantity>1;--** filters data after performing the aggregation
```

upon the difference between Having & where you can figure out exactly what you want.
** you can add the where clause to filter data first then group it. but you should know that the order is important i.e. where then group then having

Comment: @shivanirautela Show "thanks" & that an answer is the best by clicking on the accept checkmark. Not by comments. [Help] When you have enough reputation you can also upvote(/downvote) posts.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Prodid,SUM(Quantity)"QTY_SOLD"
FROM Saledetail WHERE Quantity>1
GROUP BY Prodid HAVING COUNT (Prodid)>1;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).