# SQL query to only yield multiple occurances

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mariadb and I have a table called links:

```
id | product_id | last_change
------------------------------
 1            1           xxx
 2            2           xxx
 3            5           xxx
 4            5           xxx
```

I want to find every object (3, 4 in this example) that occures more than once. Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23735892/4225972) I tried:

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) from links HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

But this results in the (adapted to this example) first row being shown and the total number of `product_id` occurrences:

```
product_id | COUNT(*)
---------------------
         1         4
```

I wanted to achieve a list of all items occuring more than once:

```
id | product_id | last_change
------------------------------
 3            5           xxx
 4            5           xxx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An aggregation function without `GROUP BY` always results in only **one** row result as it aggregates all rows

So use a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) from links GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

To see all entry with the count of the product_id , you can do following

```
SELECT l1.product_id , last_change , Count_ 
FROM links  l1 
JOIN (SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) as Count_ from links GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) l2 
ON l1.product_id = l2.product_id
```

Comment: This brings me much closer to my desired output - but only shows the number of the appearances. I want to see a list with all entries that are produced from the output. In my example your code shows ONE line for every multi-occurance, but I want to see ALL of the lines.

Comment: Hm, ok, i added a query that gives the wanted result

Comment: I get an error message: `Column 'product_id' in field list is ambiguous` trying your snippet.

Comment: yes, you have to add a identifier. see changed answer.

Comment: This was exactly what was missing. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Try below statement

```
select id, product_id, count(product_id) 
from links
group by (product_id)
having count(product_id)> 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Despite this being the exact same answer @nbk posted earlier, it is also not the exact answer to my question. My question aims for a result where every occurrence is listed, not a list with the counts of the occurrences.