# function sum() 2 fields with same id

Tags: php, mysql, sum, inner-join

I am trying to get the sum of particular field. I am getting the SUM wrong when I try to get the values together.
I have this:

- `reference: id_skill, user, level_paid`

More specifically the table reference as:

| id_skill | user | level_paid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Red | 1 |
| 100 | Red | 1 |
| 200 | Red | 2 |
| 200 | Red | 1 |

What I want as a result from my query is,

| id_skill | user | level_paid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Red | 2 |
| 200 | Red | 3 |

```
SELECT   
  SUM(level_paid) AS total,
FROM reference
WHERE user = 'Red'
GROUP BY 
  id_skill
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get the sum of the field "level_paid" if the records of "id_skill" is more than 1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Query To Obtain Value that Occurs more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095567/sql-query-to-obtain-value-that-occurs-more-than-once)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve the result with the following query. The `HAVING` clause will ensure, you are only summing the values, which are more than 1 records, based on the `GROUP BY` condition e.g. at least two `id_skill` with the same value.

```sql
SELECT
  id_skill,   
  user,
  SUM(level_paid) AS level_paid
FROM reference
WHERE user = 'Red'
GROUP BY 
  id_skill, user
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```